# How to open many shared library in different thread using dlmopen?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, shared-libraries

I need to load a shared library as many times as it needed in execution time (> 100000) in different thread for parallele execution. I don't have access to the source of this shared library and it use many global variables.That's why i would like to load X time this shared library.

I try to do this with dlmopen but actualy it  would seems from my test that is limited around 15 dlmopen on the same time.

```
void launch(int num) {
    void (*test)(int);
    char *error;

    void *handle = dlmopen(LM_ID_NEWLM, "/path/to/lib/libshared.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_LOCAL);
    if (handle == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Load shared lib [FAILED] in thread: " << num << std::endl;
        return ;
    }
    dlerror();
    *(void **) (&test) = dlsym(handle, "thread");
    if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL)  {
        fprintf(stdin, "%s\n", error);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    (*test)(num);
    dlclose(handle);
}

int main(int ac, char **av) {
    try {
        std::vector<std::thread *> vec;
        for (int counter = 0; counter < 100; ++counter) {
            std::thread *t1 = new std::thread(launch, counter);
            vec.push_back(t1);
        }

        for (std::vector< std::thread* >::iterator it = vec.begin() ; it != vec.end(); ++it) {
            (*it)->join();
            delete (*it);
        }
        vec.clear();
    } catch(std::exception const &e) {
        std::cerr << "[ERROR]: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The call to dlmopen fail after the execution of 15 threads, have you an idea or a another way to do this ?

Comment: It is not clear why would you want to load it multiple times instead of loading it just once at the beginning.

Comment: What I do to get round this problem is to copy the .so file and use `dlopen` on the copy.

Comment: This library keep in memory its context and i need as much context as thread i have launch.

Comment: I guess it would be a better idea to launch multiple child processes instead.

Comment: I can not know in advance how many dlopen i have to do.

Comment: Not sure why the call to dlopen would fail. What does dlerror() return? 
Also, sounds like a very badly written library to me. Does it have any call to reset the relevant state?

Comment: When dlmopen fail, dlerror return "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: cannot allocate memory in static TLS block". No there is not call to reset context, even if there was one I can not afford to lose the execution context.

Comment: the posted code is C++, not C.  please remove the 'c' tag

Comment: Please post a [mcve] we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: regarding */lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6:*  this is a C library.  Why open it in 'C++'?

Comment: The shared library was written in C but I would like to open it in C++ executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After research, it seems, at program startup, the dynamic linker computes all the offsets and makes sure that all threads have sufficient space for all the required thread local variables.

With dlopen, this does not work in general because it is not possible to move the thread control block around to make room for more thread-local variables. The current glibc dynamic linker reserves some space for future dlopen calls, but if you load a number of shared objects, each wither their own thread-local variables, this is not enough.That's why I get "cannot allocate memory in static TLS block".

The glibc implementation supports a maximum of 16 namespaces. I have to find an other solution.